# Why need to create a http server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, http, node-modules

In javascript, working on nodeJs, why do I need to create a server using the **http module** when I can only use the **fs module** to read and write / update data on the json file where I have my data stored?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. An HTTP server is *completely unrelated* to reading and writing stuff on the file system. These are two distinct and non-interchangeable functionalities.

Comment: you don't need it unless you are "serving" documents/data via HTTP that's why it is a server if you are only running the node engine and reading files you don't need an HTTP server.

Answer (score 1):

Creating http is only required when you want to expose some functionality via API or HTTP protocol. For processing files etc which doesnt require api exposure, you don’t need http.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use http module for working with files. fs - it's only what you need. Http module for creating a server, which can response your data by requests from the internet.

Answer (score 1):

The http module allows you to send data using `hypertext transfer protocol`.  Fs only allows you to interact with local files where as http allows you to work with files on another server or across the internet.

Answer (score 1):

The beautiful thing about node.js is that it's a generic Javascript environment.  You can solve all sorts of different problems with it and you only `require()` in or `import` the modules that you need for your task.

If your task is just reading and writing files, then you just use the modules that are appropriate for that task such as the `fs` module or perhaps a `stream` module.

Probably the most common task that node.js is used for is to create an http web server to serve web pages, both static and dynamic.  As such, a huge number of the node.js tutorials focus on how to create a web server in node.js.  But, if you  have no need for a web server in your task or for making http requests to other servers, then you certainly do not need the http module at all.